# HTML: Iframes mixed up when back button clicked

Tags: html, iframe

I have a web page that contains two iframes. When I navigate to another back and then click the browsers back button sometimes (though more than not) the the iframes are duplicated. So I have one on the left and one on the right. Both displaying different pages. When I go back the one on the right is also displayed in the one on the left.

Is this a known issue?

Regards,

Billy

Comment: can you create a sample page with the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the error? it would also help if we knew your OS, Browser, and any scripts you may be using on the page...

Comment: Personally I would not use iFrames - I don't know what it is you are trying to do but if you are loading pages which are based on the same website as the page is based then there are various other methods you can use. I would use two divs, of width 50%, which are floated next to each other. You then use `include` (for PHP), or there are a couple of methods I have used in .net, to load a page into one of the divs. If they are external pages then you might be stuck with iFrames. It is worth considering the methods I mentioned above if they are internal though.

Comment: I might give include a try I never thought of that, thanks

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any problems. I am more into .net but I'll still try to help with PHP stuff; I have a few months experience of that. If it does work then I will add it as an answer so you can mark as such.

Comment: ah some situations that would work but I just remembered that it also happens when I use the lifery CMS's iframe portlets. Unfortunately they NEED to be iframes :(